# Editing an attribute in an XML tag

Tags: python, xml

I have been trying to locate and update certain attributes in am xml file. I am using lxml in python. I have tried the following: Assume country is an attribute of the tag address.

```
    frag_xml_tree = ET.parse(xml_name)
    root = frag_xml_tree.getroot()
    for elem in root.iter('address'):
                print elem.get('country')
                elem.set('country', "USA")
                print elem.get('country')
```

When I see the two print statements I see the update but I am not seeing the update in the actual xml file. Any help with this would be really appreciated.

I was able to figure out how to write the changes to a brand new xml but how can i edit the existing xml?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: python. Sorry for the confusion. Let me edit the question

Comment: Did you  actually write the changes?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533974/python-edit-xml-file/37534064#37534064

Comment: I was able to figure out how to write the changes to a new file but not to the existing file.

Comment: You just overwrite the original file content, how else do you think file content gets changed?

Comment: I'll take a look at the link you provided. For some reason the code I posted in the question is duplicating the attribute instead of overwriting the value. Do you see anything wrong with the code I posted above?

Comment: Yes, you need to overwrite not add another attribute