# How to replace text between two tags of xml using python?

Tags: python, xml

Below is the example xml file.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                <d>TEXT</d>
            </c>  
       </b>
    </a>
```

I need to Replace "TEXT" with list of strings so that my xml look like below.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>
                <d>TEXT1,TEXT2,TEXT3</d>
            </c>  
       </b>
    </a>
```

Please tell me how can i achieve this using python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: open xml file, read lines, find the line you want to change, change it, save it --- that is a way to do it -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1591617/7383995

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = a.replace(<old string>, <new string>)
```

read file and do this operation.

Answer (score 0):

this should work,

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse('my_xml.xml')
item = doc.getElementsByTagName('d')
print item[0].firstChild.nodeValue
item[0].firstChild.replaceWholeText('TEXT, TEXT1 , etc...')

for s in item: #if you want to loop try this
    s.firstChild.replaceWholeText('TEXT, TEXT1 , etc...')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lxml` but it depends on your actual purpose of use, here is an example:

```
from lxml import etree

a = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d>TEXT</d>
        </c>  
   </b>
</a>'''

tree = etree.fromstring(a)
#for file you need to use tree = etree.parse(filename)
for item in tree:
    for data in item:
        for point in data:
            if point.tag == 'd':
                if point.text == 'TEXT':
                    point.text = 'TEXT,TEXT,TEXT'
print(etree.tostring(tree))
#<a>
#    <b>
#        <c>
#            <d>TEXT,TEXT,TEXT</d>
#        </c>  
#   </b>
#</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat an xml file just as a text file and use the functions you would use to manipulate strings. For example:

```
with open('testxml.xml','r') as f:
    contents=f.read() #open xml file

stringlist=['Text1','Text2','Text3'] #list of strings you want to replace with
opentag='<d>' #tag in which you want to replace text
closetag='</d>'

oldtext=contents[contents.find(opentag)+3:contents.find(closetag)] 
newtext=''.join(str_+',' for str_ in stringlist)[:-1] #ignore last comma
contents=contents.replace(oldtext,newtext) #replace old text with new

with open('testxml.xml','w') as f:
    f.write(contents) #write contents to file
```

There might be many instances where you have a lot of nested tags and this simple script would not work. You could use Python's built in XML editing package [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) if you want to do more advanced tasks.