# Resizing SVG Images to Specific Dimensions without Visual Alteration using Python

Tags: python, svg

I’m currently working on resizing SVG images using Python and I need some assistance. Specifically, I want to resize any given SVG image to the following dimensions:

```
width = '512'
height = '512'
viewBox = '0 0 512 512'
```

Additionally, I need to redraw the vectors in such a way that the visual representation of the image remains unchanged after resizing. **Could anyone provide guidance on how this can be achieved using Python?**

For example: I have an SVG with the following parameters: width="800px", height="800px", and viewBox="0 0 1024 1024". I want to change these parameters to width="512px", height="512px", and viewBox="0 0 512 512", and then correct all the vectors so that the image looks as it did before.

*Here are the methods I’ve already tried:*
*Using svgutils: I was able to modify the width and height, but I couldn’t figure out how to change the viewBox while updating the new dimensions of the image vector.*

```
import os
import svgutils.transform as sg

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.svg'):
        fig = sg.fromfile(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        fig.set_size(('200', '200'))
        fig.save(os.path.join(directory, 'resized_' + filename))
```

*Using Inkscape: The ‘–export-width=512’ and ‘–export-height=512’ commands didn’t work as expected.*

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os

# Get the directory of the current script
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Get a list of all SVG files in the directory
svg_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.svg'))

inkscape_path = 'D:\\Apps\\Inkscape\\bin\\inkscape.exe'

for file in svg_files:
    # Export the file as a new SVG file with a width and height of 512
    output_file = f"{file.rsplit('.', 1)[0]}_resized.svg"
    result = subprocess.run([inkscape_path, file, '--export-area-drawing', '--export-filename=' + output_file, '--export-width=512', '--export-height=512'], capture_output=True, text=True, errors='ignore')
    print(result.stdout)
    print(result.stderr)
```

*Using Cairo and rsvg: This method didn’t work on Windows. I encountered an error: “AttributeError: module ‘rsvg’ has no attribute ‘Handle’”.*

```
import os
import cairo
import rsvg

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 512, 512# desired width and height

# Get the directory of the current script
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Use os.walk to find all SVG files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.svg'):
            svg_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            png_path = os.path.splitext(svg_path)[0] + '.png'

            # Load the SVG data
            with open(svg_path, 'r') as svg_xml:
                svg = rsvg.Handle()
                svg.write(svg_xml.read())
                svg.close()

            # Prepare the Cairo context
            img = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
            ctx = cairo.Context(img)

            # Scale whatever is written into this context
            ctx.scale(2, 2)  # scale in x and y directions
            svg.render_cairo(ctx)

            # Write out into a PNG file
            with open(png_path, 'wb') as fout:
                fout.write(img.write_to_png())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591579/how-to-update-modify-an-xml-file-in-python

Comment: Why would you want to change the ``viewBox``?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman For example, I have an SVG with the following parameters: width="800px", height="800px", and viewBox="0 0 1024 1024". I want to change these parameters to width="512px", height="512px", and viewBox="0 0 512 512", and then correct all the vectors so that the image looks as it did before.

Comment: And what happens when you _not_ change the viewBox.... ?!?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman To put it briefly: if the viewBox is not changed, the SVG image will not scale properly. Therefore, any future vector edits will require scaling calculations. For better clarity, I have already found examples of the implementation of what I want to implement. I am trying to create exactly the same functionality as, for example, on this site (I mean specifically resizing): https://www.iloveimg.com/resize-image/resize-svg#resize-options,pixels.

Comment: Ok, you are working with a different type of SVG I use then. My SVGs _sized_ ``800px *800px`` display exactly the same at ``1024px * 1024px`` **_without_** changing the viewBox... _because_ they are **vectors**